# Aggregate the pandas elements according to some group allocation?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with dimensions [1,126], where each column corresponds to a specific economic variable and these economic variables fall into one of 8 groups like Output, Labor, Housing etc. I have a separate dataframe where this group allocation is described.

Is it possible to aggregate the values of initial dataframe into a new [1,8] array according to the groups? I have no prior knowledge on the number of variables belonging to each group.

here is the code for replication on smaller scale:

```
data = {'RPI':[1], 'IP':[1], 'Labor1':[2], 'Labor2':[2], 'Housing1':[3], 'Housing2':[3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
groups = {'Description':['RPI','IP','Labor1','Labor2','Housing1','Housing2'],
          'Groups':['Real','Real','Labor','Labor','Housing','Housing']}
groups = pd.DataFrame(groups)
```

The final version should look like smth like this:

```
aggregate = {'Real':[2],'Labor':[4],'Housing':[6]}
aggregate = pd.DataFrame(aggregate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge the group to the description, then groupby and sum.

```
(df.T
   .rename({0:'value'}, axis=1)
   .merge(groups, left_index=True, right_on='Description')
   .groupby('Groups')['value'].sum())
```

returns

```
Groups
Housing    6
Labor      4
Real       2
Name: value, dtype: int64
```